# Added custom styles to Visual Editor. Classes are appended and not replaced as intended

Tags: tinymce, visual-editor, post-editor

Followed several tutorials and have added custom classes in the formats section of the visual editor. The classes used are being appended and not replaced as I had intended. Is there a way to have them overwrite the existing style if there is one instead of adding to the class tag?

My use case is this: Content editor lands on the visual editor page and clicks into the visual editor. They select a piece of text and select a class from the formats dropdown I have added. They dont like the color of the link and decide to change it by going back up to the formats tab and selecting a different value. Behind the scenes, WordPress replaces the class.  I realize I could use the styles key in the json array, but that would produce inline-styles, which I'd like to avoid.

Thanks!

[image: Steps to produce issue]

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'custom_format_dropdown');
function custom_format_dropdown($settings) {
$new_formats = array(
    array(
        'title' => 'Multibox Headline',
        'selector' => 'p',
        'classes' => 'headLine',
        'wrapper' => true,

    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Link Styles',
        //'icon' => 'link',
        'items' => array(
            array(
                'title' => 'Green Bold Link ➲',
                'selector' => 'a',
                'classes' => 'listItemGreen',
                'inline' => 'span',

            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Blue Bold Link ➲',
                'selector' => 'a',
                'classes' => 'listItemBlue',
                'inline' => 'span',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
/* Check if custom "style_formats" is enabled */
if (isset($settings['style_formats'])) {

    /* Get old style_format config */
    $old_formats = json_decode($settings['style_formats']);

    /* Merge it with our own */
    $new_formats = array_merge($new_formats, $old_formats);
}
/* Add it in tinymce config as json data */
$settings['style_formats'] = json_encode($new_formats);
return $settings;
}
```